# How do I make .xls Or .pdf appear in body of email?

Tags: mailx, mail-command

I know how to attach PDF or XLS file to email as an attachment using Unix commands. I would like to know how to send these reports to email body, so that users can access it quickly, instead of extra step to open.

Answer (score 1):

## You don't

Objects may be shown "inline" along with or after the message body. This is true for HTML mails, but only for images. In any way, it is an option the recipient's mail client may offer (cf. [Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Images_in_messages_do_not_appear)), but certainly not something you can influence yet enforce as a sender. I'd actually be horrified if someone embedded potentially macro-enabled XLS in my mail.